# How can i remove completly a test case in tfs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, testcase, tfs-workitem

is there any way to remove completely a testcase from tfs 2012? I search for ways via google but it seems there is no way but maybe anyone has an special trick?

Answer (score 0):

Test cases are work items. And work items can (with standard permissions) only be set to the state "Removed".

But you can "Destroy" a workitem from the commandline to eradicate it completely. The command is:

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:http://server:port/tfs/Collection /id:1
```

You can delete multiple work items in one go by passing a comma separated list to the id parameter

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:http://server:port/tfs/Collection /id:1,2,3,4
```

See also:

- [Remove workitems permanently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx)

Comment: It seems to be that i have no rights to remove it. Is there any chance to solve this problem because when I create this workitem why it could be that then I Have no rights to remove?

Comment: In TFS it's very hard to delete anything. Almost anything  can be hidden, but to prevent the loss of history and traceability between items.

Comment: So you need to be project administrator to destroy things.